# Process each CSV files in a folder

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to import a bunch of CSV files from a specific folder and process each CSV file separately (and have the results printed for each processed CSV file).

The below code reads the interested CSV files, however when I actually attempt to process the data (last two lines of the code), I receive only one results, which corresponds to the last file read by the code. I guess, the problem is that, the code might calculate the outputs for each CSV file, however, it overwrites the actual result.

```
import os, glob

import pandas as pd

path = "J:\Tre\Data\CSVS"

for files in glob.glob("*_monday_*.csv"):

   dataframe = pd.read_csv(files, sep=",")

dataframe.columns = ["IDS", "Alfa", "Beta", "Gamma"]

Alfa = dataframe['Alfa']

Beta = dataframe['Beta']

Gamma= dataframe['Gamma']

AlfaAlfa = Beta-Gamma

sum(Alfa[AlfaAlfa==0])/Alfa.sum()
```

Comment: Well you overwrite your variable `dataframe` each time, what ultimately do you want? A list of dfs, a dict? a panel or you want all the csv's concatenated into a single df?

Comment: Hi EdChum,I would like to get a value (see last line in the code) for each CSV file printed in one document

Comment: In that case should you not indent your calculations code so it is exectued inside your for loop to achieve what you want?

Comment: actually, in the code, only the dataframe = pd.read.....line is indented, but still I get only the last calculation printed

Comment: Sorry did you understand my last comment? Your calculations code is outside the scope of your csv reading code, it will only execute when your loop completes hence a single calculation, if you wanted to calculate for each csv file, you can either move your calculation code inside your loop or create a list of dfs and loop over these dfs and perform the calculations

Comment: Thanks Ed, Indeed, I was out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a separate dataframe for each file and then join or merge all the dataframes.
More information at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

About your bug:
It is happening because you are editing the same variable over and over for each file. Hence, the overwriting.